# WPF Bindinglist tuple

Tags: wpf, data-binding

My goal is to bind to a set of objects in WPF. I first tried to use generics but horribly failed at it. Since I can't cast generic properties to INotifyProperty interfaces, to hook up the changedevent.

So I came up with this class to use as an object in my BindingList. ( Yes, I need those to notify me when an object within the list changes ). So I need your opinion, improvements on my code.

```
public class GPair : ObservableObject
{
    public GPair()
    {
    }

    private ObservableObject _first;
    public ObservableObject First
    {
        get
        {
            return this._first;
        }
        set
        {
            this._first = value;
            ((ObservableObject)value).PropertyChanged +=new PropertyChangedEventHandler(First_PropertyChanged);
            RaisePropertyChanged("First");
        }
    }
    private ObservableObject _second;
    public ObservableObject Second
    {
        get
        {
            return this._second;
        }
        set
        {
            this._second = value;
            ((ObservableObject)value).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Second_PropertyChanged);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Second");
        }
    }

    private void First_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("First");
    }
    private void Second_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("Second");
    }
}
```

The ObservableObject is just a helperclass that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged.

This piece of code allows me couple two objects in a binding... The Binding itself would look like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=First.ObjectPropertie}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Second.ObjectPropertie}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Any opinions or improvements??

Kind regards!

Comment: And in your version, this is also not done correctly.
1) You do not have an unsubscribe from the event, which is why all the previous values will remain in memory until the application ends.
2) There is also no check for null - because of this, an exception will be thrown when assigning null.
3) Casting value to ObservableObject is also nonsense. value already of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully get what you are trying to achieve, but the GPair class looks odd

What about having something like this?

```
  public class ObservablePair : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private MyObject m_First;
        public MyObject First
        {
            get { return m_First; }
            set
            {
                m_First = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("First");
            }

        }

        private MyObject m_Second;
        public MyObject Second
        {
            get { return m_Second; }
            set
            {
                m_Second = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Second");
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new 
                    PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); ;
        }
 }
```

HTH

Comment: For example, I got info from 2 objects which I want to show in one list/datagrid/etc... whatever control that is able to show lists. But I can only set the datacontext of that control to 1 object. So I'm in need of a kind of "Tuple" but with mutable data and INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.  Your code is nearly the exact same as mine. Only the PropertyChanged stuff is in my ObservableObject class, which I inherit from. But looking at your response.. it seems i'm on a good way.. :) cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the answer:

```
public class ObservablePair<T1, T2> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private T1 _item1;
    public T1 Item1
    {
        get => _item1;
        set => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Item1), _item1 = value);
    }

    private T2 _item2;
    public T2 Item2
    {
        get => _item2;
        set => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Item2), _item2 = value);
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T _)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```